# File upload restrict certain file type

Tags: php

I'm doing a file upload script that only allows jpgs.
The script that I'm using to check is

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
$size['mime'];
```

That works in most cases. However, if I have a "gif" file and I renamed the extension to "jpg", it tricks the system since the mime type for that file shows up as jpg.

How can I prevent that?

So jpg and png are allowed
Gif is disallowed

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$size['mime']` (which, as you have realised, is the MIME-Type and thus not entirely reliable), use `$size[2]`.

[The manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) says that it contains

> one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of the image.

A comment further down the page conveniently lists those constants:

```
 1 = GIF
 2 = JPG
 3 = PNG
 4 = SWF
 5 = PSD
 6 = BMP
 7 = TIFF (Intel byte order)
 8 = TIFF (Motorola byte order)
 9 = JPC
10 = JP2
11 = JPX
12 = JB2
13 = SWC
14 = IFF
15 = WBMP
16 = XBM
```

This information is generated by examining the file itself and, as such, is the most reliable mechanism at your disposal.

Comment: @leonbloy: Aha, there it is! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I have a "gif" file and I renamed the extension to "jpg", it tricks the system since the mime type for that file shows up as jpg.

Extract the file base name (without extension) using [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$file =
 pathinfo("myFakeGifImage.jpg", PATHINFO_BASENAME); // returns myFakeGifImage
```

and  add the extension based on the file type that `getimagesize()` returns, not what the user tells you.

Comment: I don't understand what removing the extension will accomplish, other than making the `$file` variable useless for actually accessing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want jpegs then load it with [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) which returns FALSE on errors for bogus jpegs.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is also able to detect the MIME Type of a file, i.e. by using `mime_content_type`. This is a safe method since it actually inspects the file's contents.