# why my uploading image code accept avi and flv files

Tags: php, image-uploading

I write php code to allow user to submit image and upload it to the server. I get it working and the server receives the image. But it seems like the server is accepting even .avi and .flv files. I do write if/else statement for checking whether a file is an image, but why it doesn't work? Thank you

This is my php code

```
$tmpPath = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$movedPath = "submit-img/" . $_POST["category"] . "/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

$fullURL = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$query = explode("&", $fullURL["query"]); //only choose first query
$prevPage = "gallery.php" . "?" . $query[0];

//I get the file type here
$fileType = strpos($_FILES["image"]["type"], "image/");

//if its not an image then redirect to the previous page and send a message
if ($fileType === false || ($_FILES["image"]["size"]) == 0 || $_FILES["image"]["size"]/1024 > 5000){
    $prevPage = $prevPage . "&imgSubmit=none#imgSubmitForm";
    header("Location: " . $prevPage);
}else if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 0){ //if file is an image
    if (!is_file($movedPath)){
        move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, $movedPath);
    }else{
        while (is_file($movedPath)){    
            $extension = strrchr($movedPath, ".");
            $movedPath = str_replace($extension, "", $movedPath) . "1" . $extension;
        }
        move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, $movedPath);
    }
    $prevPage = $prevPage . "&imgSubmit=submitted#imgSubmitForm";
    header("Location: " . $prevPage);
```

}

Comment: where are you filtering for only images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload restrict certain file type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099968/file-upload-restrict-certain-file-type)

Comment: It looks like you're only checking whether the file has an extension and whether the files size is not 0 and less than 5MB.  I bet you could upload any file to it

Comment: Isn't it "$_FILES["file"]["type"]" ?

Comment: ^^^^ depends on the name used on the OP's form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
}else if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 0){ //if file is an image
```

The comment on this line is fundamentally misleading. The `size` key in `$_FILES` is the size of the file in bytes; it has nothing to do with whether the "file is an image". (In particular, it is *not* the physical size of the image.)

If you need to test whether a file is an image, your best bet is to use the [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function. This function will return the size of an image if it's an image type that PHP recognizes, or zero if it doesn't appear to be an image.

Do not use the `type` field of the `$_FILES` array to determine whether a file is an image. This field is populated by the browser, not by the server, and may contain misleading and/or flat-out incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but your code is highly vulnerable to attacks:

1) You don't check for upload success, and assume it DID succeed. Always check for upload failure before you do anything:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['image']['error']);
}
```

2) You're using the `['type']` field for your validation. That's a USER-SUPPLIED value, and cannot be trusted. A malicious user can trivially manipulate that value to say `image/jpeg` but still be uploading `nastyvirus.exe`.

3) You're using the `['name']` field for storing on your server. That is also user-supplied data, and can be trivially manipulated to including pathing information, e.g. `../../../../../../../etc/passwd`. Since you're using it blindly, you're allowing malicious users to scribble on any file on your server that the webserver has access to.

Comment: thanks for pointing those out. Can u tell me how to fix number 3? Thanks